# how to remove a character at the end of a string in linq c#

Tags: linq, trim

I have the following LINQ query; I want to remove dot character if available at the end of string

```
var hatoList = (from L in db.vHatoList select L.HatoFullName.Trim('.')).ToList();
```

Comment: Okay, so you've got some code... what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently trying to perform the query in the database. We don't know what database technology you're using, so it's hard to know whether there's some way to make it *actually* happen in the database, but it's probably simplest to do in memory instead (given that it won't change how many records will be returned). The `AsEnumerable()` method is used to just change the compile-time type to `IEnumerable<T>` (instead of `IQueryable<T>`) forcing the rest of the query to be evaluated in .NET code instead of in the database:

```cs
var hatoList = db.vHatoList 
                 .AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(entry => entry.HatoFullName.TrimEnd('.'))
                 .ToList();
```

(I've also changed the call from `Trim` to `TrimEnd` to avoid it removing periods at the start of the string.)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `linq to sql` and database does not understand `TrimEnd` or `Trim`.

So first you have need to load data in memory and then use `TrimEnd`  method.

```
var hatoList = (from L in db.vHatoList select L.HatoFullName).ToList().
             Select(t=>t.TrimEnd('.'));
```

Comment: No, `Trim('.')` won't remove *all* periods - it will only remove those at the start and the end. But more importantly, the OP hasn't said what actually happens with their current code. It may well be that they're facing a rather more significant issue than just the removal of leading periods as well as trailing ones.

Comment: Thanx 4 ur answer dear, but at both case  trim or trimend it shows the same error "The method 'System.String TrimEnd(Char[])' is only supported in LINQ to Entities when there are no trim characters specified as arguments.'
"

Comment: @jon-skeet Yes your right. I edit the definition of `Trim` in my answer

Comment: @NuzheenKazim: Right, so that's what you should have included *in the question*. Currently your question doesn't tell us *anything* about what's wrong.